# Upload files to different directories in Classic ASP

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I am making a classic ASP page in which I need to have a form upload multiple files.

I am using an upload.asp class file by [Jacob "Beezle" Gilley](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19297/Pure-ASP-File-Upload.htm).

The files are uploading, but the problem I am having is that I want to upload each file to a different sub directory.

For example, my form has the following fields:

```html
<input type="file" name="PDF" />
<input type="file" name="Powerpoint" />
<input type="file" name="Thumbnail" />
```

And here is the current ASP:

```vb
savepath = "/assets"
For Each File In Uploader.Files.Items  
    'Change Filename  
    origFile = File.FileName  
    extension = InStrRev(origFile, ".")  
    cutString = Len(origFile) - extension + 1  
    File.FileName = metaID & right(origFile, cutString)  
    path = path & File.FileName  

    ' Save the file
    File.SaveToDisk savepath

    ' Output the file details to the browser
    Response.Write "File Uploaded: " & File.FileName & "<br>"
    Response.Write "Size: " & File.FileSize & " bytes<br>"
    Response.Write "Type: " & File.ContentType & "<br><br>"
    ThumbName = File.FileName
    ThumbSize = File.FileSize
Next
```

I want the file in the PDF field to go to  the `/assets/pdf` subfolder, the file in the Powerpoint field to go to the `/assets/PPT` subfolder and the file in the thumbnail field to go to the `/assets/thumb` subfolder.

As far as I can tell, the current code only loops through the files  regardless of what the field name is.

Is there a way to change the savepath based on the field name.

Comment: Also, apologies for the code not all being in a code block. I have indented each line with 4 spaces, but it only starts the code block about half way down for some reason.

Comment: Hit enter after is the current ASP:... to ident correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've inserted a line....

```vb
' every type a different directory
savepath = savepath & "/" & extension

File.SaveToDisk savepath
```

that should do the trick